# Infinite Sum of a Converging Series of Inverse Cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to find the value of d for the following converging infinite sum:

$$
\sum_{n=2 }^{\infty}\arccos \left ( -\frac{d^{n+1}+d^{2n}+d^n-d}{(d^{n-1}-1)(d^n-d)} \right ) = \pi
$$

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of $d$?

Comment: $d$ is a positive real number between 0 and 1 that I'm trying to find. In my specific case I know the solution to the sum is $\pi$. I realize that wasn't clear before

Comment: The minus sign, is it for the term $d^{n+1}$ only?

Comment: It's for the entire fraction

Comment: When I tried programmatically finding a possible value the closest I got was the fraction 13/23 which is greater than $\sqrt{2}-1$, how'd you find that inequality though?

Comment: Looks like I miscalculated.

Comment: I noticed your Comment about trying some numerical values programmatically, but it would improve the Question to include an explanation of this in the body of the Question.